# Django Form not being displayed

Tags: python, django

I have been working on a personal project for a bit now and have been unable to resolve an issue I have been having with a particular form. I have written successful Django forms in the past and have modeled it after those but I am still unable to get it to display.

My model looks like:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
director = models.CharField(max_length=50)
genre = models.TextField()
rating = models.IntegerField()
mpaa_rating = models.CharField(max_length=5)
# movie_file = models.FileField()
movie_cover = models.CharField(max_length=100)
cast_list = models.TextField()
year = models.TextField()
url = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='http://www.imdb.com/title/')
```

My form like:

```
class Meta:
    model = Movie
    fields = ['url', 'name', 'director', 'genre', 'rating', 'mpaa_rating',   'movie_cover', 'cast_list', 'year']
```

View:

```
context = RequestContext(request)
movie_form = MovieForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    movie_form = MovieForm(data=request.POST)
    if movie_form.is_valid():
        url = urlrequest.urlopen(movie_form.url)
        movie = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')
        movie_form.set_name(movie.find(itemprop='name'))
        data = get_movie_data(url)
        movie_form.data['name'] = data[0]
        movie_form.data['director'] = data[4]
        movie_form.data['genre'] = data[7]
        movie_form.data['rating'] = data[3]
        movie_form.data['mpaa_rating'] = data[2]
        movie_form.data['year'] = data[1]
        movie_form.data['cast_list'] = data[5]
        movie_form.data['movie_cover'] = data[6]
        movie_form.save()
        print('movie added')

return render_to_response('add_movie.html', {movie_form: 'movie_form'}, context)
```

And finally Template:

```
<form id="movie_form"  method="post" action="{% url 'add_movie' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ movie_form.as_p }}

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

I have read several posts on stack overflow about how to fix the issue but none of them have fixed mine yet.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You're not sending the form to the template:

```
return render_to_response('add_movie.html', {movie_form: 'movie_form'},
```

Replace with this:

```
return render_to_response('add_movie.html', {'movie_form': movie_form})
```

UPDATE

By the way, you should use `render()` instead, as it uses the  `RequestContext`.

If you want to use it on the template with `render_to_response` you'll have to add the parameter `context_instance=RequestContext(request)`, which can be a bit annoying.

Comment: maybe you forget to add quotes to the movie_form key

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure that was part of it but the form is still not loading. I looked at my other forms that are working and did not even notice i reversed them.